# when creating a pivot chart in MS Access, how to prevent it from updating with every change?

Tags: microsoft-access, pivot-table

I'm creating a pivot chart view of some data in MS Access 2010. I'm working with a large data set so every operation takes a long time.

My problem is that access automatically re-creates the pivot chart view with every change i make:
once after setting the series field,
again after setting the values field,
again after setting the categories field etc.
waiting for the chart to be recreated after every change like that is a complete waste of time and it's driving me mad.

I'd like to be able to make all the changes i want and only then hit a button and have access generate the chart, a sort of "apply" button. is it possible in any way ?

Comment: Check the defer layout changes option on the pivotchart view.

Comment: @soandos - This seems like a very specific and most likely correct answer.  Why do you make it as a comment instead of an answer?  Not a criticism - I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @DaveBecker, I know that is how to do it in excel, but I did not have access on the machine that I was working on at the time. Now that I am checking, I cannot find that option.

Comment: @soandos glad to hear that, i thought there was something wrong with me not finding that..

Comment: @yurib, I don't think there is an equivalent option in Access. No idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Ctrl+N` keyboard shortcut, then `Ctrl+O` to open the existing database in a separate window, edit the fields using DataSheet view, save the edits, then switch back to the first instance.

> When you remove a field from a chart, the data is still available via the field list, but it is not displayed in the chart.

As a modern alternative, use the enhanced PivotChart and PivotTable capabilities in Excel with the ability to connect to an Access database.

**References**

- [Keyboard shortcuts for Access - Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-70a673e4-4f7b-4300-b8e5-3320fa6606e2)
- [Create PivotTable or PivotChart views in an Access desktop database - Access](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-pivottable-or-pivotchart-views-in-an-access-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752)
- [Discontinued features and modified functionality in Access 2013 - Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-access-2013-bc006fc3-5b48-499e-8c7d-9a2dfef68e2f)
- [Connect to an Access database - Excel](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/connect-to-an-access-database-a3d6500c-4bec-40ce-8cdf-fb4edb723525)